# How can I make my laptop webcam show a preset image or video?

Tags: webcam

I am using a HP laptop, windows 10 with built in webcam.
An online account is asking me to verify myself by taking a photo of my ID through my webcam. I do not currently have a physical copy of the document but I have a photo saved on my desktop.

When the account asks to take a photo of my ID using my webcam how do I show the image already saved on my computer? Thanks for any help

Comment: The whole idea of this process is that you *cannot* show an image. They actually want to see you and the physical ID together, in motion.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying Daniel. The account just asks for a photo but they do not have an upload file from computer, only the option to take a photo with the webcam. I checked the process and they don't record the video, just take a snapshot then upload from that. They might secretly be saving as a video, but what they say and what the website asks for is just a photo.

Comment: Hm, okay. You should probably just contact them instead of trying to “hack it”.

Comment: I'm with Daniel B. The app is likely looking for you to have the physical original of the requested documentation. It's a bad idea to try and fake it.